# Protractor test cases are failing on Jenkins server but they pass on Local machine: Error: Element is not clickable at

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have written as script in which I create one form and then Delete it. While creating and deleting one modal dialogue box appears on the screen and "Create" & "Delete" buttons are present on the Modal Dialogue. When I execute this script in my local machine, test script is running fine but when I run the same on Jenkins server, test script will fail with below message:

```
[31mUnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (370, 24). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal-backdrop fade" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-style="{'z-index': 1040 + (index &amp;&amp; 1 || 0) + index*10}" modal-backdrop="" style="z-index: 1031;"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=37.0.2062.124)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)[0m
```

Here is my test script:

```
describe('Tests Scripts', function () {
    var baseurl = `"http://test/index.html"`;
    var url = `"/index.html"`;
    var driver = browser.driver;
    var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    var tabIndex = 1;

    beforeEach(function () {
        ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    });

    it('WILL load the page', function () {
        browser.get(baseurl);
        helper.waitForElementByXpath('//*[@id="xyz"]/ul/li/a/i');
        expect(browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.xpath('//*[@id="xyz"]/ul/li/a/i'))).toBeTruthy();
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain(url);
    });

    it('Delete the form', function () {
        element(by.xpath('//*[@id="xyz"]/ul/li/a/i')).click().then(() => {
            helper.waitForElementById('controlItem');
            element(by.id('controlItem')).click().then(()=> {
                helper.waitForElementById('modalDialogue');
                var form_name = "DeleteForm";
                element(by.id('title')).sendKeys(form_name);
                browser.wait(function () {
                helper.clickByIDAndWait('createbutton');
                tabIndex++;
                    return true;
                }, 5000).then(function () {
                browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (curr_url) {
                    var arr_url = curr_url.split(':');
                    var instance_id = arr_url[arr_url.length - 1];
                    helper.clickByXpathAndWait('//*[@id="windowTab-1"]/a');
                    helper.waitForElementById('form-control');
                    var xp = '//*[@id="Forms-' + instance_id + '"]/td[2]';
                    expect(driver.isElementPresent(by.xpath(xp))).toBeTruthy();

                    element(by.id('deleteForm-' + instance_id)).click().then(()=> {
                        helper.waitForElementById('DeleteFormModal');
                            browser.wait(function () {
                        helper.clickByIDAndWait('modal-deleteForm-btn');
                                return true;
                            }, 5000).then(function () {
                        helper.waitForElementById(form-control');
                        expect(driver.isElementPresent(by.xpath(xp))).toBeFalsy();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Here are the functions used in above code:

```
var clickByIDAndWait = function (btnId) {
    var returnVal = false;
    browser.wait(function () {
        if (!returnVal) {
            element(by.id(btnId)).click().then(function () {
                returnVal = true;
            });
        }
        return returnVal;
    }, 30000);
};

var waitForElementById = function(elementId){
    browser.wait(function(){
        return browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.id(elementId));
    },30000);
};
```

Comment: I would recommend adding a screenshot reporter such as https://www.npmjs.org/package/protractor-screenshot-reporter. This will let you see the state of the browser and why your script is not able to click on the button.

Comment: @codemonkey, test cases are failing bacause there are animations in the screen. Modal dialogues are animations and hence they are failing.

Comment: I'm using protractor on a page which has css transitions, and these all work. The WebDriver/Protractor API waits for the promises for the elements to be resolve and then attempts to interact with the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

Test cases are working fine on jenkins now after making some changes in the test cases. I think the problem was, once the focus is at the bottom of the page it was not going up automatically to click on the element, I restructured the test cases in such a way that my list will not be too long and focus will not go at the bottom of the page. Also, I am resetting the window size before every test case by using below line of code in beforeEach function:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);
});
```

I am not sure whether my assumptions are correct and resolution will work for everyone but its working fine for me. you may want to give a try and see.

Comment: Hello, I've had this issue on servers like Jenkins as well. It is usually the screen size causing the problem. I checked by getting screenshots at the failure point, then noticing the size was all off and elements were off screen.  If it happens in the future, looks like youre all set by changing the screensize!